# TimeValue error in IIF

Tags: sql, ms-access

Query:

```
SELECT
    IIF(ISERROR(TimeValue(cdp.date_ivr_start)),1,0) AS tTime
FROM
    call_detail_paste AS cdp
```

This is a simplified version of what I am trying to do. In the `call_detail_paste` table, there are date/time fields that have a `null` value. I only want the time portion of fields so I apply the `TimeValue()` function to get just the time part. Obviously, if the field is a `null` value, there will be an error, so I nested an `ISERROR()` inside an `IIF()`.

What is happening:

```
  Date/Time Value        Expected        Actual
07/01/2014 12:15:62         0              0
      null                  1            #Error
```

In the final version of the query, if there is no error it will output the `TimeValue` while if there is an error, it will return `null`.

Any ideas how to get this to work right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of IsError. Or use a IsNull with IIf.

```
SELECT
    IIF(IsNull(cdp.date_ivr_start), 1, 0) AS tTime
FROM
    call_detail_paste AS cdp
```